# line 8: 'empty'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

I was watching the django tutorial in youtube, and I follow the same step as the professor did. The error came out with the following error:

`line 8: 'empty'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

```html
  <h1>My To do list </h1>
  <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Items</th>
        </tr>
    {% for task in tasks % }
      <tr>
        <td>{{task.title}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% empty %}
      <h3>No items in list</h3>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: Are you using Django or Jinja2?

Comment: Django Version 3.2.7

Comment: Typo: Use proper spacing for your template tags please. I believe in the line `{% for task in tasks % }` the `% }` is the problem, it should be `%}` with no space between the percent sign and the brace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem occurs because you have a space here `{% for task in tasks % }` between '%' and '}'.
Change it to `{% for task in tasks %}`